# The expression for Paneitz operator in even dimensional sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, induction, riemannian-geometry, laplacian

The Paneitz operator in even dimensional sphere is defined by
$$
P_n=\prod_{k=0}^{\frac{n-2}{2}}(-\Delta+k(n-k-1)),
$$
where $\Delta$ is the laplacian on sphere with usual metric $g_{S^n}=(1-x^2)^{-1}+(1-x^2)g_{S^{n-1}}$.

Consider a axially symmetric function on the sphere, say $u=u(x)$. Clearly,
$$
P_2(u)=-\Delta u=|g|^{-1/2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(|g|^{1/2}g^{11}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})=(1-x^2)^{-n/2+1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}((1-x^2)^{n/2-1}(1-x^2)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})\\ =(1-x^2)u''-nxu'=-[(1-x^2)u']'.
$$

Direct computation then shows
$$
P_4(u)=[(1-x^2)u']^{(3)}.
$$

In this paper [Improved Beckner's inequality for axially symmetric functions on $S^n$](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123621004171?via%3Dihub), the author claims when n is even,
$$
P_n(u)=(-1)^{n/2}[(1-x^2)u']^{(n-1)},
$$
but I have no idea how to prove this. I have tried to use induction and write
$$
P_{n+2}=\prod_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}(-\Delta+k(n-k+1))=\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}(-\Delta+k(n-k+1))(-\Delta)=\prod_{k=0}^{\frac{n-2}{2}}(-\Delta+(k+1)(n-k))(-\Delta)\\=\prod_{k=0}^{\frac{n-2}{2}}(-\Delta+k(n-k-1)+n)(-\Delta),
$$
but I do not know how to continue.

This question should be simple and dose not rely on additional advance knowledge. Appreciate any help!